# How to Upload an Image with Tasker to an S3 Server via HTTP Post or REST using AWS Access and Secret Keys?

Tags: http, put, tasker

I am working on a project where I need to upload images to an AWS S3 bucket using either HTTP Post or REST API. I have the AWS Access Key and Secret Key, but I'm not entirely sure how to utilize them in this context.

I've done a bit of research and found that it's possible to interact with S3 using various SDKs or even directly with HTTP requests. However, I'm a bit lost on how to structure the request, especially when it comes to securely incorporating my AWS credentials.

Could anyone provide a step-by-step guide or point me towards resources that could help me understand how to achieve this? I would really appreciate any help or examples, especially if you have code snippets to share.

Thank you in advance!

I tried different methode with http put request but nothing works

Comment: You mentioned Tasker in both your title and the tags, but it's not mentioned in your question. You ask for code snippets to share... Are you hoping this code lives within Tasker? On a server acting like an AWS proxy of sorts? If you could clarify how you want Tasker and the example code involved, that would help with coming up with a specific solution.